# Capturing save events on Lightning detail page inside a component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning, lightning-experience

So I have a Lightning component on a Lightning detail page. Whenever a user updates some value on the record, I want to refresh this component. Basically want to pull in some fields based on the changed values.

But how to find out that a save event has occurred. The save is not in any of my components where I can fire an event. This is the standard save feature of salesforce.

I tried this, but this handler keeps getting called even if nothing is done.

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.oppty.StageName}" action="{!c.refreshPage}"/>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_valueChange.htm

What am I doing wrong? Any other way to do achieve this?

**EDIT**

Ok finally this worked for me

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.refreshPage}" />
```

But I uncovered another issue on the Opportunity page. 
This event does not fire when I change the Stage on the standard Sales path component. But it does fire when I edit the record by clicking the "Edit" button and then saving the record.

Seems to be an inconsistent behavior. Anyone else notice this issue?